# Return sequence of generic type from parent class

Tags: class, generics, nim-lang

In the example below, I have a `Foo` object that has a generic `T` and a `foo` field of type `T`.

The `Foo` is inheritable and has a proc named `test` that should create and return a sequence of type `T` as defined by a subclass.

In the latest version of my code, there's an error on the first line of the `test` proc:

> cannot instantiate: 'T'

---

If I get rid of the `S` type and replace it with `FooP`, the error goes away, but then I get an error on the `discard b.test()` line:

> type mismatch: got (BarP)

---

Here's the code:

```
type
    Foo[T] = object {.inheritable.}
        foo:T
    FooP[T] = ref Foo[T]

proc test[S, T](self: S): seq[T] =
    var f: T = self.foo
    var s: seq[T] = @[f]
    s   


type
    Bar = object of Foo[int]
    BarP = ref Bar 

var b: BarP = new(Bar)

discard x.test()
```

I'm sure I've just got it all messed up. Could someone please tell me how `test()` in this situation could successfully return a sequence of the type of `T` as defined by the subclass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inheritance with generics not working is a known bug: https://github.com/nim-lang/Nim/issues/88

You can work around this by not specifying the type at all, as in test3 here:

```
type
  Foo[T] = object {.inheritable.}
    foo: T
  FooP[T] = ref Foo[T]

# Only works for Foo[T]
proc test[T](self: Foo[T]): seq[T] =
  @[self.foo]

# Only works for ref Foo[T]
proc test2[T](self: FooP[T]): seq[T] =
  @[self.foo]

# Workaround:
proc test3(self): auto =
  @[self.foo]

type
  Bar = object of Foo[int]
  BarP = ref Bar

var a = new Foo[int]
var b: BarP = new(Bar)
var c: Bar

echo a.test3()
echo b.test3()
echo c.test3()
```

Comment: Thanks again, that totally took care of it. Good to know it's just a bug. It had me running in circles for hours! :-)